# How often should a mining pool be notifying workers about new work (cancelling current jobs)?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, proof-of-work, stratum

I'm trying to get a handle on the Stratum mining pool protocol.  If I set up a mining pool client, I will initially get something to work on.  Let's say it takes me a while (e.g. an hour) to solve the problem at hand.  Since blocks get mined on the Bitcoin network around every ten minutes, should I expect to get a message from teh pool during that hour that I'm working on the initial problem notifying me to move on to other work?

I ask because I set up a test client and as I monitor network traffic I notice I'm not getting a response from the pool, which leads me to wonder if there's something wrong on the pool's end or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If it's taking you more than a few seconds to finish a work unit, there's really no point in mining at all. Given that you talk about "solve the problem at hand", it sounds like you don't really understand how mining works. If you can't find a share every few seconds, the pool is giving you work units that are too hard and the difficulty should be adjusted. Otherwise, the pool can't accurately measure your hash rate and can't compensate you accurately.

Comment: Hey I'm a fellow David, don't flame me brother!  Let me try a follow-up . If the worker has not submitted anything back to the pool, how often would one expect a pool to send mining.notify messages back to the worker?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that a pool would only specify "clean jobs" (abort work in progress if possible) when a new block was found by the network. Most miners can't abort the 2^32 hashes with different nonces but can stop trying different extra nonces or ntimes.